# What are patchsets of a git repository

Tags: git

I can pull the newest files from my   repository, but when pushing even one file, the error shows:

abc.git is not configured to receive patchsets.

I try to cancel my commit using `git reset --soft` command, and then commit again,but the problem still exists.

Comment: I think this message is sent by the server. What kind of service do you use to host your central git repository ? `github` ?

Comment: Is the error coming from [gitblit](https://github.com/gitblit-org/gitblit/blob/41e6a701953c6f3ec0c4b2375426e4205a1c6a00/src/main/java/com/gitblit/git/GitblitReceivePack.java#L328)? Are you perhaps using `git review` (Gerrit)?